# jQuery video on ended function -> How to reset video?

Tags: jquery, video

I'm trying to build an instagram story like interface on my website. When a video finishes, it goes to the next video. If the last video is reached, it begins from the start. It's almost working, but somehow I think it doesn't reset the time to 0 in the videos. After clicking for the next slide, the previous video is just paused, but I want it to play from the beginning every time.

html:

```
<section id="stories">
  <div class="videos">
  </div>

  <div class="bar">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var triggers = $('div.bar div.item');
  var videos = $('video');
  var lastElem = triggers.length - 1;
  var target;

  triggers.first().addClass('active');
  videos.hide().first().show().get(0).play();


  function sliderResponse(target) {
    console.log('Start!');
    videos.hide().eq(target).show();
    triggers.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');

    var current = videos.eq(target).get(0);

    //here I reset the time
    current.currentTime = 0;
    current.play();

    //function for finished video
    videos.eq(target).bind('ended', function(){
      target = $('div.bar div.active').index();
      target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target + 1;
      sliderResponse(target);
    });
  }

  triggers.click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
      target = $(this).index();
      sliderResponse(target);
      //resetTiming();
    }
  });

  $('video').click(function() {
    target = $('div.bar div.active').index();
    target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target + 1;
    sliderResponse(target);
    //resetTiming();
  });
})
```

Comment: Try giving each video an `ID`, then when video is playing it's name is the `currentID` and when a new video is selected you say.. (1) CurrentID video must `seek` to zero and pause (2) Next the `currentID` itself is also updated to become the newly selected video's ID.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out how to use the playlist plugin, which covers everything I needed.